# It it possible to run 5V led strips with a 12V Power supply?

Tags: led

I am working on a LED project involving 5V led strips. I did some calculations using the  WS2812B led strips and found that I need ~100W. I took the cheapest power supply available where I live but it delivers 12-24V. Is it possible to arrange the LED strips in a way that the voltage would add up to the output of my power supply?

Comment: What do you mean by "delivers 12-24V"? One or the other? It is adjustable in that range? Please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the LED strips.

Comment: The power supply can output 12,15,16,18,19,20,22,24 V. http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/553088/ETC2/WS2812.html                   I bought the LED strip from ebay: https://www.ebay.com/itm/WS2812B-Strip-LED-Lights-5050-RGB-30-60-144-LED-M-IC-Individual-Addressable-DC5V-/223222365145?var=&ef_id=CjwKCAjw-ITqBRB7EiwAZ1c5UzdCuqKg0lFe53rS2zAbmFIquxmbMFasd_M9zM2anT9cVr-6uGFj2xoCpjYQAvD_BwE:G:s

Comment: You must use a DCDC-converter to bring down the voltage to 5V.

Comment: You should use a power supply capable of 5v and 20amps or more. Ideal for that is an smps taken from old PC. Cheap, and great current capability at 5v.Just one minor modificationi required to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting two in series is not going to work, since you'd then have to interface the serial data line.
You could however use a small DC-DC (such as the many LM2596 based) to convert 12V down to 5V. It would also reduce the current requirements in the wiring.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It seems to be the only option currently and I have found a suitable converter. I just have one more question. If I connect two strips in series would the voltage drop to a lower voltage than 12V say 6V for each strip?

Comment: @user199289 That is not safe with WS2812B strips because the voltage won't be shared evenly. (Imagine one strip has all the LEDs off, and the next strip has all the LEDs on)

Comment: @immibis Exactly what I said ….you can't stack the string in series for voltage ….so what are you saying??

Comment: The reason it won't work is not because of the serial data line. (but that is one reason)

Comment: @immibis Then please tell me why using a DC-DC convertor won't work.

Comment: @user199289 Yes, you can put two strips in series. Feed the power (from the 12-5V convertor) to the center of the two strips. Connect your data lines in series output of one strip to input of the next) and drive from the input end.